# How do I get all the values of a String array to use in a return statement in a method?

Tags: arrays

This is the code I have which is being used to create a test question in a quiz application. This method returns the question and lists the values in a String array as the multiple choice answer options. I am not sure if this is the correct way to get the values out of the array to be displayed with the question.

```
public String getQuestion() {
    String answers = null;
    for(int i = 0; i <= myAnswerList.length; i++)
    {
        answers += myAnswerList[i];
    }

    return this.myQuestion + " \nanswers"; 
}
```

Comment: Java, sorry I forgot to mention that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few minor things to fix:
Loop condition should be

```
for(int i = 0; i < myAnswerList.length; i++)
```

also, the way you wrote your for-loop, every answer will be concatenated together with no spaces, so maybe try:

```
answers += myAnswerList[i] + "\n";  //add new line after every answer
```

and if you are trying to return a string you should so something like this:

```
String output = this.myQuestion + "\n" + answers;
return output;
```

You could also use a for-each loop to simplify some things, this is what method would look like with all the fixes:

```
public String getQuestion() {
  String answers = "";

  for(String line: myAnswerList) {
    answers += line + "\n"
  }

  String output = this.myQuestion + "\n" + answers;
  return output;
```

}

Comment: This basically what I ended up doing. Although I haven't learned the format that your for loop is written in yet so I kept it the way I had it but fixed the i < myAnswerList.length. Thank you for confirming what I figured out. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would define a question class that has a list of answers and return that.

```
public class Answer {
    public string AnswerText {get; set;}
}

public class Question {
    public List<Answer> Answers {get; set; }
}
```

In your class that calls getQuestion, you should return the question object you're looking for that contains its answers.

```
public class MainClass {
    public List<Question> Questions {get; set;}

    public Question GetQuestion(/* some criteria, like question number or something */) {
        var selectedQuestion = // get the question from Questions based on some criteria

        return selectedQuestion; 
    }
}
```

And then do whatever you need to do in the presentation layer for the end-user to show them the question and answers.